# Dropwizard is not purging old log files as configured in the logback config file

Tags: java, logback, dropwizard

My group is using Dropwizard as our framework. Currently, we're configuring Logback to the following value for the archiveFileCount:

```
archivedLogFilenamePattern = ${logRoot}"/trace-"${serviceId}"-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz"

archivedFileCount = 48
```

Based off of this configuration, logs should be rolled over every hour and there should be two days worth of logs.

What we're actually seeing is a log file count of 92. On top of that, the log files left behind, seem to be random hours from random days (see snippet at the end of this post).

I tried using the debug flag for logback to see how logback is doing the file rollover and old file purging, but I don't see any logback specific debug messages in the logs in the STDOUT

```
-Dlogback.debug=true
```

Does anyone know how to enable debug for logback in the Dropwizard framework? Here's the version info:

Dropwizard: 3.1.2
Logback: 1.1.7

```
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-26-18.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-26-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-26-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-27-15.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-27-18.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-27-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-02-27-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-02-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-02-18.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-02-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-02-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-02-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-03-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-03-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-03-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-04-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-04-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-04-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-05-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-05-18.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-09-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-09-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-09-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-10-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-11-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-11-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-11-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-12-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-12-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-12-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-12-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-12-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-13-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-17-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-17-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-17-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-17-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-18-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-18-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-18-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-20-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-23-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-24-00.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-24-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-27-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-27-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-27-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-27-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-27-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-00.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-01.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-02.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-03.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-04.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-08.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-09.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-10.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-11.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-12.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-13.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-14.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-15.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-18.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-19.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-20.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-21.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-22.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-28-23.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-00.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-01.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-02.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-03.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-04.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-08.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-09.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-10.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-11.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-12.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-13.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-14.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-15.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-16.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-17.log.gz
trace-fakeServiceId-2019-03-29-18.log.gz
```

Comment: Don't think 3.1.2 is a valid version for dropwizard. Can you verify and update your question - https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/releases

Answer (score 0):

From the Logback documentation for [TimeBasedRollingPolicy](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#TimeBasedRollingPolicy), the filename pattern for hourly rollover schedule is `%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}`

In your case, the archivedLogFilenamePattern should be

```
${logRoot}"/trace-"${serviceId}"-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log.gz"
```

Hope that works for you.